# UI C# sub ArrayList

Tags: c#, user-interface, arraylist, arrays

As I'm building my first UI program in C#, I am facing some troubles!
Assuming I have two Classes (`Country`, `City`) then I set each new `Country` object in An `ArrayList` created before and named `CountryList` as following:

```
public static ArrayList CountryList = new ArrayList();

Country c1 = new Country(string name); // Creating Country object

CountryList.Add(c1); // Store the Object c1 in ArrayList
```

As every `Country` has its own `Cities` so I can't create an `ArrayList` to store all `City` objects together !
Then, I want like a Sub-ArrayList in `ArrayList`.

Comment: Your `new Country(string name)` is illegal.  And you should avoid using `Arraylist` -- use `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
public class City
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Country 
{ 
  public string Name {get; set;}

  public List<City> Cities {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have Country be a string, make it an object.

```
public class Country
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public IList<string> Cities {get; set;}
}
```

Then you'd have

```
Country country = new Country{Name = "England"};
country.Cities.Add("London");
CountryList.Add(country);
```

Comment: sorry, but how to call "London"(city object) using "England"(country object), can I ? then I suppose each new city is an Object !

Comment: Yes, if you need a City object, you could call each city like something along the lines of Country.Cities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "London");